# Doesn't show "(1)" for a recently voted for close question

Tags: bug, ios-app

For a recently voted for close question doesn't show "(1)" near "close" button/indicator.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open question with no close votes
2. Vote for close via button:

   > [image: close]
3. The button has changed to:

   > [image: close1]
4. Refresh question by pulling it down
5. Button showed without (1) again:

   > [image: close]
6. Refresh a lot of times
7. See (1) again:

   > [image: close1]

---

1. App Version: 1.6.1.2
2. Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
3. OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Comment: Probably caching on the API side